# How do I set adaptive multiline UILabel text?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UILabel` named `titleLabel` in my **storyboard** nib set to its default height. I want it to *programatically* expand in height to fit it's content. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
// just setting content
titleLabel.text = "You don't always know what you are getting with mass-market cloud computing services. But with SimpliCompute, the picture is clear. SimpliCompute gives you powerful virtual servers you can deploy using just your web browser. That’s enterprise grade technology you can deploy and control on-the-fly."

titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0

titleLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 700

titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping

titleLabel.sizeToFit()
```

None of this works for me in any combination! I always only see one line of text in my `UILabel`. What am I doing wrong?

I absolutely need the text content to be variable.

Comment: Did you try setting height to something really high?

Comment: like in the thousands?

Comment: Are you using autolayout? because then you should call the update constrains methods.

Comment: and which property do you mean when you say height?

Comment: @rckoenes I am not using autolayout explicitly (It's turned on though) - should I? Just for the label?

Comment: By height I mean height. If your height is to low, there won't be enough space to display multiple lines.

Comment: @MarcMosby there is no `height` property on UILabel - so `titleLabel.height = 500` won't work. How exactly do I set the height programatically?

Comment: If it is turned on it means that you are using it, you should just add the correct contsrains in interface builder. Or tun Autolayout off.

Comment: Well it should have a frame, and the height of that frame could be changed.

Comment: @MarcMosby I do not wish to physically change the frame in the storyboard

Comment: @AmitErandole either use AutoLayout, this is the easiest option. Or turn it off. If autolayout is turned on in the storyboard all ui element that do not have constraints are layout as they are in the Interface Builder. \

Comment: ou can set the height programmatically, but if your constraints are keeping it there, it won't budge. The other option is to have a constraint with a flexible height, and modify the constraint at the top or bottom as needed.

Comment: @Matthew How do I set "constraint with a flexible height"? Do it through interface builder or programatically?

Comment: As with any IBOutlet or IBAction you can just drag a line from the constraint in the storyboard to your controller. This connection will be of type NSLayoutConstraint, and you can then set `constraint.constant = 500` to set the new height.

Comment: @MarcMosby I took the vertical constraint and added it to the controller as you said and set the constant/ But these are the results: http://cl.ly/image/0O2X3Y2k2z1p

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I kind of got things working by adding auto layout constraints:

[image: auto layout contraints]

But I am not happy with this. Took a lot of trial and error and couldn't understand why this worked.

Also I had to add to use `titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0` in my `ViewController`

Comment: @MarcMosby Could you explain why this worked? Also I did not add any outlets to my controller etc.

Comment: Why are you not happy with your solution? `numberofLines = 0` means numberOfLines is infinity. As for your constraints, you have a fixed width and a dynamic height. If you want to set the height of your label dynamically according to the amount of text, I can give you a code snippet on how to do so.

Comment: I guess I am unhappy because I don't understand Auto Layout too well. But I am remedying that now. Thank you for your quick explanation and pointing me in the right direction. Could you give me that code snippet for reference as well?

Comment: Wow, this idea made my day!! I guess that 2 years later you already know why, but it works because with the top constraint you give the point where it has to start and if it needs extra lines it grows to the bottom because there's no fixed height for the label or bottom constraint.

Answer (score 28):

I know it's a bit old but since I recently looked into it :

```
let l = UILabel()
l.numberOfLines = 0
l.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
l.text = "BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH"
l.frame.size.width = 300
l.sizeToFit()
```

First set the numberOfLines property to 0 so that the device understands you don't care how many lines it needs.
Then specify your favorite BreakMode
Then the width needs to be set before sizeToFit() method. Then the label knows it must fit in the specified width

Comment: This is not a good solution. Think of all the different screen sizes, in both portrait and landscape. Statically setting the width to 300 would not be pretty on all of them.

Comment: @Sti You're right. But you can set the width dynamically as follow : `l.frame.size.width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * percentage`. Then, the width of the label will adapt according to the width of the screen. Obviously, this is a dummy example, you can then adapt according to whether the device is an iPad or and iPhone, etc.

Comment: That's still not dynamic. It won't work when you rotate the device.

Comment: You 're right about the orientation. And from what I recall about this solution, I guess I have been using `viewWillTransition` or the `NotificationCenter` class. Although, I'd use the storyboard's constraints for any recent project, even if it doesn't work well with the native UIScrollView

Comment: Yeah, but using `viewWillTransition` for TableViewCells? Meh.

Comment: This works well for me whilst using a dynamic width.

Comment: This works great even with dynamic width, or autolayout for rotation.   I set width, top, left, center anchors with Autolayout, and leave height to manage the frame.    I even have a second label below that is anchored to the label's bottom anchor and it works great.

Comment: Instead of giving it a fixed frame size `l.frame.size.width`, you can provide leading and trailing constraints, which is better than a fixed width.

Answer (score 27):

This is much better approach if you are looking for multiline dynamic text label which exactly takes the space based on its text.

No sizeToFit, preferredMaxLayoutWidth used

Below is how it will work.

[image]

Lets set up the project. Take a Single View application and in Storyboard Add a UILabel and a UIButton. Define constraints to UILabel as below snapshot:

[image]

Set the Label properties as below image:

[image]

Add the constraints to the UIButton. Make sure that vertical spacing of 100 is between UILabel and UIButton

[image]

Now set the priority of the trailing constraint of UILabel as 749

[image]

Now set the Horizontal Content Hugging and Horizontal Content Compression properties of UILabel as 750 and 748

[image]

Below is my controller class. You have to connect UILabel property and Button action from storyboard to viewcontroller class.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!
var count = 0
let items = ["jackson is not any more in this world", "Jonny jonny yes papa eating sugar no papa", "Ab", "What you do is what will happen to you despite of all measures taken to reverse the phenonmenon of the nature"]


@IBAction func updateLabelText(sender: UIButton) {
    if count > 3 {
        count = 0
    }
    textLabel.text = items[count]
    count = count + 1
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //self.textLabel.sizeToFit()
    //self.textLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 500
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Thats it. This will automatically resize the UILabel based on its content and also you can see the UIButton is also adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Superb Solution Brother..!! Hats Off

Comment: works great.. can you explain why did you change the priority to 749?

Comment: Arun, I have a similar problem trying to accomplish the same results but so far all the suggestions I have received do not work.  Would you be able to look at my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46716123/automatically-increase-decrease-uilabelview-height-in-uitableviewcell/46722394#46722394 and help me solve my constraint issue?  Your post here was excellent!!

Answer (score 21):

It should work. Try this

```
var label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10
    ,100, 300, 40));
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16.0);
label.text = "First label\nsecond line";
self.view.addSubview(label);
```

Comment: But I don't want to set an explicit frame because the text content will be variable

Comment: you can get the size of a your String, and apply that size.height to label

Comment: there must be a better way no? that sounds like a terrible solution. IOS8 layouts are meant to be adaptive and flexible

Comment: yeah I agree. But need to explore. If you find anything please answer it, so it will help others as well.

Comment: You should be able to use just .Center. In swift, there's type inference, and since the property is of type NSTextAlignment, theres no need to put it there.

Answer (score 11):

With Graphical User Interface (GUI) in Xcode, you can do the following:

> - Go to "`Attribute Inspector`" and set `Lines` value to `0`. By default, it is set to `1`.
> - The Label text can be written in multi-line by hitting `option + return`.

[image]

> - Now, go to "`Size Inspector`" and set the `width`, `height`, `X` & `Y` `position` of the Label.

[image]

That's all.

Comment: question how to set alignment of the text top-left?

Answer (score 3):

Programmatically, Swift

```
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
label.titleView.numberOfLines = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

**Programmatically in Swift 5 with Xcode 10.2**

Building on top of @La masse's solution, but using autolayout to support rotation

Set anchors for the view's position (left, top, centerY, centerX, etc). You can also set the width anchor or set the frame.width dynamically with the UIScreen extension provided (to support rotation)

```
label = UILabel()
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
self.view.addSubview(label)
// SET AUTOLAYOUT ANCHORS
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
label.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
// OPTIONALLY, YOU CAN USE THIS INSTEAD OF THE WIDTH ANCHOR (OR LEFT/RIGHT)
// label.frame.size = CGSize(width: UIScreen.absoluteWidth() - 40.0, height: 0)
label.text = "YOUR LONG TEXT GOES HERE"
label.sizeToFit()
```

If setting frame.width dynamically using UIScreen:

```
extension UIScreen {   // OPTIONAL IF USING A DYNAMIC FRAME WIDTH
    class func absoluteWidth() -> CGFloat {
        var width: CGFloat
        if UIScreen.main.bounds.width > UIScreen.main.bounds.height {
            width = self.main.bounds.height // Landscape
        } else {
            width = self.main.bounds.width // Portrait
        }
        return width
    }
}
```

Comment: where `self.leftAnchor` comes from?

Comment: .leftAnchor is the NSLayoutAnchor from the superView...  The example code considered that the UILabel was embedded in another view (self).    To make it easier to understand, I changed it to self.view (assuming that the UILabel was added in a ViewController's view)

Comment: Your answer should not used external confusing variables. Example code should reflect minimal *workable* property.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension UILabel {

    var textSize: CGSize { text?.size(withAttributes: [.font: font!]) ?? .zero }

    func setSizeForText(_ str: String, maxWidth: CGFloat) {
        text = str
        let dividedByMaxWidth = Int(textSize.width / maxWidth)
        if dividedByMaxWidth == 0 {
            frame.size = textSize
        } else {
            numberOfLines = dividedByMaxWidth + 1
            frame.size = CGSize(width: maxWidth, height: frame.size.height * CGFloat(numberOfLines))
            sizeToFit()
        }
    }
}
```

sizeToFit() in the end will shrink the label's width to the widest line after word break

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me:

- Set the `numberOfLines` property of `UILabel` to 0
- add this line: `yourLabel.sizeToFit()` after assigning text to the `UILabel`