# Show text dynamically while scrolling up fetch data from server

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit

class Profile: UIViewController,UIScrollViewDelegate,UITextViewDelegate{


@IBOutlet weak var tx: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var sc: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var l1: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var l2: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var l3: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var l4: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var l5: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var l6: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var l7: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var l8: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var l9: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var l10: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var l11: UILabel!



@IBOutlet weak var l12: UILabel!



@IBOutlet weak var l13: UILabel!



@IBOutlet weak var l14: UILabel!



@IBOutlet weak var l15: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var l16: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var l17: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var l18: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var l19: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var l20: UILabel!



var toPass:String!
var toPass1: String!

var toPass2: String!
var toPass3: String!
var toPass4: String!
var toPass5: String!
var toPass6: String!
var toPass7: String!
var toPass8: String!
var toPass9: String!
var toPass10: String!

var toPass11: String!

var toPass12: String!
var toPass13: String!
var toPass14: String!
var toPass15: String!
var toPass16: String!
var toPass17: String!
var toPass18: String!
var toPass19: String!
var toPass20: String!


override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    l1.text = toPass
    l2.text = toPass1
    l3.text = toPass2
    l4.text = toPass3
    l5.text = toPass4
    l6.text = toPass5
    l7.text = toPass6
    l8.text = toPass7
    l9.text = toPass8
    l10.text = toPass9
    l11.text = toPass10
    l12.text = toPass11
    l13.text = toPass12
    l14.text = toPass13
    //l15.text = toPass14
    l16.text = toPass15
    l17.text = toPass16
    l18.text = toPass17
    l19.text = toPass13
    l20.text = toPass20
    tx.text = "\(toPass20)" + "\(toPass20)" 

    sc.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    sc.maximumZoomScale = 10
    sc.delegate = self



}



func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(sc: UIScrollView)
  {


    NSLog("hello")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

}
```

I am creating labels statically. I want to create dynamically, while scrolling I need to fetch data from server and display dynamically.

Comment: Why aren't you using a tableView?

Comment: i want to display data side by side   not in an order.

Comment: give sample code how to use table view please

Comment: You should check some tutorials first: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uht9xMj2sB0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set dynamic height to UILable using my this method...

```
-(CGRect)calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:(NSString*)resizableLable :(CGFloat)hightofLastLable
{
    CGSize constrainedSize = CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width , 9999);

    NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:11.0], NSFontAttributeName,
                                          nil];

    NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"textToShow" attributes:attributesDictionary];

    CGRect requiredHeight = [string boundingRectWithSize:constrainedSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];

    if (requiredHeight.size.width > [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width )
    {
        requiredHeight = CGRectMake(0,hightofLastLable,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width , requiredHeight.size.height);
    }
    return requiredHeight;
}
```

Add UIlable and setFrame

```
UILabel *lblAddress = [[UILabel alloc]init];
[lblAddress setFrame:[self calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:@"your Text" :lastLable.X+lastLable.Hight+5]];
lblAddress.text = @"your Text ";
lblAddress.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Add now add Lable in  scrollview

```
float fscrview = lblAddress.frame.origin.y + lblAddress.frame.size.height + 20;
yourScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width , fscrview);
[yourScrollVieww addSubview:lblAddress];
```

hope help you solve your issue..

Comment: tanks but iam using swift language  it is in objective c..  can u post same in swift please

Comment: i haven't started yet swift, but you can check links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134905/how-do-i-set-adaptive-multiline-uilabel-text-in-a-swift-ios-project, http://harishkumarkailas.blogspot.in/2015/01/uiscrollview-uilabel-changes-size.html