# How to allow user to enter multi-line text Swift (Like Facebook or Twitter posts)

Tags: ios, swift

I know I can use a text view but its awkward with the keyboard on smaller iPhones.  And it looks odd being able to scroll and write in a box.

I want to have something like a Twitter post box or Facebook post box or contacts (extra information box).  One that expands as the user writes more.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please add a picture of how you want it here?

Comment: I can't post images until I have 10 reputation.  But if you have an iPhone go to the contacts app.  Look at the notes section.  When you start typing it gets bigger and you can scroll around.  Thats exactly what I want.

Comment: I guess this is already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134905/how-do-i-set-adaptive-multiline-uilabel-text-in-a-swift-ios-project).

Comment: Is that for expanding a text box as the user types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, make your view controller implement UITextViewDelegate,

```
 class YourViewController: UIViewController,  UITextViewDelegate {

         @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
           ...
 }
```

In the viewDidLoad method, set the delegete,

```
self.textView.delegate = self
```

Finally you should implement the textViewDidChange method.

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {

       let textViewFixedWidth: CGFloat = self.textView.frame.size.width
       let newSize: CGSize = self.textView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(textViewFixedWidth, CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)))
       var newFrame: CGRect = self.textView.frame

       var textViewYPosition = self.textView.frame.origin.y
       var heightDifference = self.textView.frame.height - newSize.height

       if (abs(heightDifference) > 20) {
           newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmax(newSize.width, textViewFixedWidth), newSize.height)
           newFrame.offset(dx: 0.0, dy: 0)
        }
        self.textView.frame = newFrame

  }
```

Comment: Will that allow the user to type and the box expand as they type?

Comment: Yes, it will. You just need to implement something in textViewDidChange method according to how you want to expand. I updated my answer with a sample code that I used in one of my previous projects. It was expanding the box after exceeding some height. You can change it to achieve an expansion like you wish but mine can show you some direction I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have a text view - which resizes every time the text changes. I am not sure on swift, but on obj-C, override the `-textViewDidChange` method and resize using :

```
#pragma mark - UITextViewDelegate
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    [self resizeTextView];
}

- (void)resizeTextView {


        [self.textView sizeToFit];
            self.textView.frame = CGRectMake(self.textView.x, self.textView.y, __device_width, self.textView.h);
}
```

There should probably be something similar in Swift.