# How to convert Int to String.CharacterView.Index

Tags: string, subscript, swift2

This is driving me nuts.

In Swift 2.2, it makes it impossible to subscript `String` with `Int`. For example:

```
let myString = "Test string"
let index = 0
let firstCharacter = myString[index]
```

This will result with a compile error, saying

> 'subscript' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with an Int, see the documentation comment for discussion

One workaround I see is to convert integer to the index type, but I can't figure out how..

Comment: Swift suddenly became really hard to use with 2.2...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get nth character of a string in Swift programming language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092884/get-nth-character-of-a-string-in-swift-programming-language)

Comment: It was never possible to index a string with an `Int` in Swift.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It annoyed the heck out of me too so I wrote an extension to deal with it:

```
extension String {
    subscript (index: Int) -> Character {
        let charIndex = self.startIndex.advancedBy(index)
        return self[charIndex]
    }

    subscript (range: Range<Int>) -> String {
        let startIndex = self.startIndex.advancedBy(range.startIndex)
        let endIndex = startIndex.advancedBy(range.count)

        return self[startIndex..<endIndex]
    }
}

// Usage
let str = "Hello world"

print(str[0])       // H
print(str[0..<5])   // Hello
```

Updated for Swift 4.x:

```
extension String {
    subscript (index: Int) -> Character {
        let charIndex = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: index)
        return self[charIndex]
    }

    subscript (range: Range<Int>) -> Substring {
        let startIndex = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: range.startIndex)
        let stopIndex = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: range.startIndex + range.count)
        return self[startIndex..<stopIndex]
    }

}

let s = "‍‍‍ family"

print(s[0])      // ‍‍‍
print(s[2..<8])  // family
```

Comment: how would the solution look like without extension?

Answer (score 18):

It's not that subscripting is impossible necessarily, it just takes one extra step to get the same results as before. Below, I've done the same thing as you, but in **Swift 2.2**

```
let myString = "Test string"
let intForIndex = 0
let index = myString.startIndex.advancedBy(intForIndex)
let firstCharacter = myString[index]
```

**Swift 3.x + 4.x**

```
let myString = "Test string"
let intForIndex = 0
let index = myString.index(myString.startIndex, offsetBy: intForIndex)
let firstCharacter = myString[index]
```

*EDIT 1:*

Updated code so you can use the `Int` that was passed into the "index" value elsewhere.

---

*Syntax Edits:*

I'll consistently update this answer to support the newest version of Swift.

Comment: This does the trick, but what about converting the other way?

Comment: Taking an .Index type and turn it into Int.

Comment: Are you looking to directly convert `Index` to `Int`, or are your looking to use the `Int` to find a character in a `String`?

Comment: No for other use. I needed an int so I can manipulate another array at the corresponding index according to the Character. I ended mapping the CharacterView into array of Characters then work with it. Still not ideal since it wastes time on conversion :(

Comment: I've updated my answer so you can re-use the `Int` passed into "index".

Comment: @ZGski when I tried to insert "\n" at the middle it removed half of the string. But it works well when I use normal characters. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: @JkAlombro What does your `String` look like exactly?

Comment: @ZGski The string looks like this `5B495473-ED0A-4516-ACBC-C2F36B59EED5`. I want to insert "\n" in the middle so that the other half goes to next line but it removes the half of the string instead

Comment: @JkAlombro This sounds like an issue related to the way your `UILabel` is set up... See **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134905/how-do-i-set-adaptive-multiline-uilabel-text)**.

Comment: @ZGski yeah, seems like I didn't need to insert newline after all. All I had to do is set the number of lines allowed for my UILabel to 2. Thanks sir.

Answer (score 4):

An example for swift 4:

```
let myString = "Test string"
let index = 0
let firstCharacter = myString[String.Index(encodedOffset: index)]
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy cheat is to convert the string to an array of characters, which you can index with an Int:

```
let a = Array("hello")
for i in a.indices {
   print(a[i])
}
```

Answer (score -1):

ZGski answer updated to Swift 3

```
let testText = "Test text 123"  
let position = 11  
let index = testText.characters.index(testText.startIndex, offsetBy: position)  
let character = testText[index] // "2"
```