# Swift 3 - UIScrollView

Tags: json, uiscrollview, swift3

I need a little advice on the following problem.

In my App I call JSON data from the server, however I have no control on how much text each field will have.

Say Description: it could be anything from a single word to 1000 words.

I am looking for the Best approach on displaying an unknown amount of text

i.e. My terms and conditions is 5000 Words, but the Privacy policy is only 2000 words.

Comment: I Found a solution here, it seems to work well

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MsgWhqcRYNY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scrollview Keep LABEL and make LINES of label as 0. set top,bottom,leading and trailing constraints.

as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24136440/5413426