# ios auto layout label positionning

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout

I am working with the storyboard using auto layout.

I need a particular layout and I am not able to find a way to do it.

I have two UILabels, the first one regular and the second one bold (That's why I used two UILabels).

I need the second UILabel to be near the second. But if the second label does not have enough space to displayed, then I want it to wrap the text.

[image: image in english, need to be wrapped]

[image: xcode]

Comment: You should use a single text field with attributed text. Set lines to 0 to allow the text field to expand

Comment: @jipo64 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134905/how-do-i-set-adaptive-multiline-uilabel-text. CHECK THIS URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your storyboard, set property of textfield as lines=0 give below constraints only

1. Top leading trailing to supverview
2. Height with relationship greaterthanequalto

Note: don't give bottom constraint to label

To make some part of label bold use NSAtrributeString. Don't take two labels.

Comment: Thank you! I go for using  NSAttributeString with a single UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

**Case I :** If you want to adjust font size in the same line then,

1. Vertical space from SE CONNECTOR button
2. Leading constraint to superview
3. Trailing constraint to superview

& add code to adjust font,

```
yourLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
yourLabel.minimumFontSize = 8;//Keep min font size you wants
yourLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

**Case II :** If you don't want to adjust font size & achieve it in multiple lines then,

```
yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

1. Vertical space from SE CONNECTOR button
2. Leading constraint to superview
3. Trailing constraint to superview
4. Give Greater than equal height constraint(& set constant to 0)