# Automatically increase/decrease UILabelView Height in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, constraints

Hello I have a UITableView with x# of cells.  the last cell I have two UILabels.  When the second UILabel text is set I am trying to get the cell and the UILabel to resize to show the text.

Here is what I have:

The UILabel - LabelBio (orange) has:

Lines: 0
Baseline: Align Baselines
Line Break: Word Wrap
Autoshrink: Fixed Font Size

[image]

The constraints for ContentView, LabelSellerInfo and LabelBio are set as follows:

LabelSellerInfo
[image]

LabelBio
[image]

ContentView
[image]

With those settings here is what a get:
[image]

I have tried many  variations but cannot seem to get the Bio label to grow and shrink, sometimes if I get the label to grow the cell is still too small.

Can anyone help me to understand what I am doing wrong and show me how to get the constraints correct to get this to work?

Thank you

Comment: if you want label to adjust height according to content provide these constraints -: leading, trailing,top and height with height relation greater then or equal + number of lines = 0 for label.

Comment: Are you setting `.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`?

Comment: So I have 4 constraints on the LabelBioView.  1) Trailing Space to Superview,   2) Leading Space to Superview,    3) Top Space to: LabelSellerInfo,    4) Height >= 90.   But it does not work, do I have them wrong?  Oh, one difference is that I define the method heightForRowAt and return UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Answer (score 0):

1. Set tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
2. Remove this function in your code func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
3. Set height constraint of LabelBio greaterOrEqualThan 0

Comment: So I added the three constraints like Tushar suggested but it did not work, so I removed the function heightForRowAt and changed the height constraint to >= 0 but it still does not work right.

Answer (score 0):

here are the steps ...

- hope you know about `autylayout`. use constraints (`left to content view`, `right to content view`, `bottom to content view` and `verticle to your first label`)
- then in your `viewdidLoad` method add `YourTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200` -> give any height you want.
- finally define below method :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

you good to go.

Comment: I thought that was how I have the constraints