# How do you show multiple lines of text in a UILabel using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

Is it possible to show multiple lines of text in a `UILabel` in Swift?

I currently use a `UITextView` which has an internal scroll and I would like to avoid a scroll and display statically. I’ve tried placing a number of constraints to achieve this but it doesn’t prevent an internal scroll on the `UITextView`.

Comment: set `label.numberOfLines = 0` to have unlimited amount of rows and `textField.isScrollingEnabled = false` to inactivate the scroll in the text field

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134905/how-do-i-set-adaptive-multiline-uilabel-text

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you mean `UITextView`.

Change your text to a `UILabel` and hook it up as an `IBOutlet` and then add the following code:

`myLabel.numberOfLines = 0`

Example:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myLabel.text = "This is where all of your text goes..."
    myLabel.numberOfLines = 0

}
```

Set your constraints as normal and this should display the `UILabel` on multiple lines dependent on how much text you have displayed.

Comment: Thank you this makes much more sense

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do the following :

`myLabel.numberOfLine = 2`

You can also specify `0` to allow your label to use the necessary number of line to display all the content.

Answer (score 1):

**You can do that Using StoryBoard also:**

Make the lines to **0** or any amount of lines you want

[image]